# Why is it eligible for a Java class to declare and initialize an object of that class in a method?

Tags: java

I have the following code example:

```
public class example {

  // class constructor
  public example(){}

  public void foo() {
    example o = new example();
    ...
  }
}
```

Why can this be compiled and run instead of leading to a `StackOverflowError`?

Comment: why not? you have to call `foo()` somewhere, why should it lead to a stackoverflow. I mean, it's not called in the constructor...and by the way compile vs. runtime

Comment: one can instantiate object from anywhere(if constructor is accessible). So limitation on this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You claim that this would lead to a `StackOverflowError`. However, a `StackOverflowError` will only occur if a method calls itself, either directly or indirectly, indefinitely.

In your case, `foo` must call itself to make a stack overflow happen. Let's see what `foo` does.

```
example o = new example();
```

When `foo` is called, it would call the constructor of `example`, which you have declared here:

```
public example(){}
```

The constructor does nothing before returning. Now that the constructor has returned, `o` is assigned the newly created instance, and `foo` returns since it has nothing else to do. Note that `foo` has not been called again.

Your misunderstanding might be that you wrongly thought that when the constructor is called, all of the methods of that class are also called. This is not true, unless you actually call the methods in the constructor:

```
public example(){ foo(); } // this will cause stack overflow
```

Comment: Yes, my prior understanding is that an object of that class is declared and initialized using the class constructor, all of its methods are like 'pre-loading' to the memory and I think such kind of operation would lead to stack overflow :)

Comment: And what if I create another class with only the main method, and I do the following things in the main method:  example o = new example();   o.foo(); is it eligible?

Comment: @Q.Z.Shen my answer is based on the assumption that `foo` is called somewhere, such as `main`. See the phrase “when `foo` is called” at the start of the third paragraph? If you don’t even call `foo`, not even the constructor is called.

Answer (score 2):

Only reason this works:  `foo` isn't being invoked as part of `example`'s initialization.

The JLS [defines a lifecycle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5) of what happens when a class is newed up.

In this case, these two lines are relevant:

> Each of these situations identifies a particular constructor (§8.8) to
>   be called with specified arguments (possibly none) as part of the
>   class instance creation process.
>
> Whenever a new class instance is created, memory space is allocated
>   for it with room for all the instance variables declared in the class
>   type and all the instance variables declared in each superclass of the
>   class type, including all the instance variables that may be hidden
>   (§8.3).

So that means that unless you ran out of memory during object allocation, you're not going to run into any problems.

You explicitly call out `StackOverflowError` which only happens with recursive calls which go *way* too deep.  This can only happen if you do something silly like this:

```
class Example {
    Example e;
    public Example() {
        e = new Example();
    }
}
```

Every invocation of `new` will force this object to `new` another object until you run out of heap space, simply because `new`ing the object depends on itself being `new`ed.

You can accomplish the same thing if you invoke `foo` in your constructor, too.

```
class Example {
    Example e;
    public Example() {
        foo();
    }

    public void foo() {
        Example o = new Example();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Example();
    }
}
```

So long as `foo` isn't called when the object is being instantiated, in *this* case, a declaration such as what you have won't result in a `StackOverflowError`.